# Image not showing backend nor frontend-magento 1.9.3.1 v

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9.3.1 for one of my stores. Everything is working fine but when I upload images, the success message appears but the image is not showing in the back end nor in the front end.
PFA [image]

this is the demo I have attached.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by wrong permission set to uploaded files..

Open `lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php` and make sure following permission are set:

Around line 219:

```
chmod($destinationFile, 0666);
```

Around line 541:

```
if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0777, true))) {
```

**AND**

**Make sure your /media folder is writeable.**

```
sudo chmod 777 -R media/
```

after setting the permissions don't forget to clear the cache and reindex

Comment: Thanks Bilal for your response but the following article has been solved my issue  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154112/uploading-image-issue-in-magento-1-9-3-1